# Cython: Error in math expression (works fine in Python)

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to cythonize my Python code to improve performance.

I didn't make any change to my original python code, I just run the `setup.py` and get the .c files.

Now I have this issue: when I perform a basic math operation in Python, it works fine, while in Cython it doesn't work as expected.

The code snippet is the following, here I try to calculate the *y*-coordinate of a given *x* on a circle of center [3,0] and radius 1:

```
import math
import numpy as np

def calculateY(x, center, radius):
    a = -2*center[0]
    b = -2*center[1]
    c = center[0]**2 + center[1]**2 - radius**2
    tmp = (b)**2 - 4*(c) - 4*(a)*x - 4*(x**2)
    return 1/2*(-b + math.sqrt(tmp))       ###### I only want the y>0

C1, R1 = [3,0], 1

Pstart = np.array([2.13766028, 0.50633014])

print(calculateY(Pstart[0], C1, R1))
```

If I run this in Python, I get `y = 0.5063301366799338` which is the right result.
If I cythonize the code and then run it by `import my_code`, I get `y = 0.0` which tells me that the `y` is empty (actually the code doesn't even print anything, I got this from another function where I print the y)

Am I doing something wrong whit the syntax?

Thanks in advance.

---

Edit:

here's my `setup.py`:

```
import distutils.core
import Cython.Build
distutils.core.setup(
    ext_modules = Cython.Build.cythonize("my_code.pyx"))
```

I run the cython version with:
`import my_code`

The output is empy.

---

**EDIT 2:**
Thanks to joni, I changed the division in my original code and now it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that `cdivision=True` is enabled inside your `setup.py`. In C, the division of two integer literals cuts off all decimal places. Consequently, the `1/2` inside your return statement equals `0.0`. Instead, simply use floating-point literals, i.e.

```py
# my_code.pyx
def calculateY(x, center, radius):
    a = -2*center[0]
    b = -2*center[1]
    c = center[0]**2 + center[1]**2 - radius**2
    tmp = (b)**2 - 4*(c) - 4*(a)*x - 4*(x**2)
    return 1.0/2.0*(-b + math.sqrt(tmp))           # <--- Note the 1.0/2.0
```

Then, after installing the Cython module by `python3 setup.py install`, you can use it from Python:

```py
# mwe.py
from my_code import calculateY
import numpy as np

C1, R1 = [3,0], 1
Pstart = np.array([2.13766028, 0.50633014])
print(calculateY(Pstart[0], C1, R1))           # Output: 0.5063301366799338
```

Note that a Cython `.pyx` file only contains the function and class definitions. You have to call your cythonized module's functions from Python.

Comment: Thank you but I'm still getting nothing even with the 1.0/2.0... Btw, the ```cdivision``` is not set in my setup.py. What if I just set ```cdivision=False``` instead of editing all of the divisions in my original code (which is made of many functions etc. etc.)?

Comment: @user14520608 Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your error. Your code works fine for me in Python and Cython. And there's no need to set `cdivision=False` since it's already set by default.

Comment: Please see the Edit in the question

Comment: EDIT 2: Thank you, I tried to put the ```.0```s in my original code and now it works!